# window.print():  не закрывается вкдалка при окончании печати

Tags: печать, javascript

Есть страничка для распечатки, перед распечаткой я скрываю часть элементов, а часть показываю (с помощью css);

После распечатки эта вкладка должна закрыться; прописываю обработчик события
`<body onafterprint="self.close();">` в таком случае закрывается, только когда из меню выбираю печать, когда же в коде вызываю `window.print()` не закрывается, если вывожу обработчик события `onafterprint` в отдельную функцию и ставлю туда `alert("...")` перед закрытием окна, то `alert` выводится и после нажатие на ОК всё равно вкладка не закрывается (пробывал в `Chrome, Opera, FireFox`). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, атрибут `onafterprint` не входит в спецификацию, и поэтому поддерживается не всеми браузерами (только IE и FF). Во-вторых, те браузеры, которые его поддерживают, работают с ним по-разному (IE вызовет функцию ещё до начала печати, а FF - после закрытия диалога печати, даже если пользователь нажал "Отмена"). Я бы посоветовал сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
<html>
    <body onload="doPrint()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function doPrint() {
                window.print();
                window.close();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```